# How to integrate a Power BI report into a UWP C# application

Tags: c#, uwp, jwt, powerbi-embedded

I am developing a UWP application to display reports I have created to the user. However I cannot seem to produce the necessary security token to authenticate the report once I have it's embed URL.

I have tried embedding the report into an iFrame within the webview to display it in a similar style to the web app however, the iFrame doesn't load a public report compared to the webview which can.

Any examples seem to use JwtSecurityToken, but this is not currently compatible with UWP applications.

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;

public string Generate(string accessKey = null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.AccessKey) && accessKey == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessKey));
    }

    accessKey = accessKey ?? this.AccessKey;

    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(accessKey);
    var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest);
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(this.Issuer, this.Audience, this.Claims, DateTime.UtcNow, this.Expiration, signingCredentials);

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

Is there a way around this package without making the reports embed URL public? Or perhaps a way to incorporate it into the application? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the iFrame doesn't load a public report compared to the webview which can"? Actually I can load the completed report in WebView, maybe a screenshot is helpful to understand your issue

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT if I have an iFrame within my WebView (which was done so that I can use the JavaScript PostMessage function) then that is unable to load a publicly available report, whereas the WebView without the iFrame can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Microsoft.PowerBI.Core` [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerBI.Core/) that contains APIs to generate your report embed tokens.  These tokens should be generated on the server and not in the client code so you do not expose your Azure access key.

Take a look at our [sample on Github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app/blob/master/EmbedSample/Controllers/DashboardController.cs#L55) for more info.

```
var embedToken = PowerBIToken.CreateReportEmbedToken(workspaceCollection, workspaceId, reportId);

var jwt = embedToken.Generate(accessKey);
```

Comment: The whole issue is that these are not compatible with my UWP app